# Null Pointer Exception when requesting Audio Focus

Tags: android

Here is my code:

```
int result = am.requestAudioFocus(audio_listener,AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT);
if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(NumbersActivity.this,onwhich_isClickedN.getAudiofile());
    mediaPlayer.start();
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(on_comp);
    }
```

Here is the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.media.AudioManager.requestAudioFocus(android.media.AudioManager$OnAudioFocusChangeListener, int, int)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: `am` is null. YHou didn't initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have initialised your AudioManager before you use it.
`am = (AudioManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);`

Here's some more information on [tutorialspoint website](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_audiomanager.htm) that may help you.